# Problems with Bluebox and Smartfox 2X

Tags: flash, smartfoxserver

im starting with smartfox for my projects, as far i have read the documentation for it, i wanted to use the bluebox stuff, but, my SmartFox Server 2X it's not generating the httpbox.do file, which i really need.

How I can make smartfox start correctly bluebox and get this file?

I have tried checking if there is any problem on SmartFox startup, and so, fix those errors, so it would do a clean start, after that, the file wasnt generated still

Comment: For server questions... Use your account to ask at: [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: I think you're getting silence on both sites because there is not enough info to **recreate** your problem and help you... **(1)** _" ...I have read the documentation"_ what link? When I check the docs of [version 1](https://www.smartfoxserver.com/docs/1x/docPages/blueBox/overview.html) and [version 2](http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/GettingStarted/bluebox) it says it's enough to just re-compile (output) a new SWF using the latest SmartFox server files.

Comment: **(2)** What happens when you **trace** the `connectionMode` (see [from docs](https://www.smartfoxserver.com/docs/1x/docPages/as2/html/it_gotoandplay_smartfoxserver_SmartFoxClient.html))? If `socket` is said to be the type, then it should also mean Bluebox part is working okay.... **(3)** Are you testing on a server (can be web or local host)? What happens if you access `http://127.0.0.1:8080/BlueBox/HttpBox.do` (replace 127.0.0. etc with your own server IP address). **(4)** Are you getting any security errors? Like a bad `crossdomain.xml` access?